# Use a find() result throughout the entire cakePHP website

Tags: cakephp

I've made a footer element that will be shown throughout my entire website.

The content of this page needs to be filled up with data from a certain model, on every page it is shown.

```
$sponsors = $this->Sponsor->find('all',
        array('conditions' => array("NOT" => array("Sponsor.logo_id" => null))));
```

But where is the best place to define this? I thought in the app_controler, but how to do so isn't exactly clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `AppController`'s `beforeFilter` or possibly `beforeRender` (I never really noticed the difference); making sure your `AppController` has access to `Sponsor` model.

```
// app_controller.php
function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->loadModel('Sponsor');
    $this->Sponsor->recursive = -1; // adjust to return more/less data
    $sponsors = $this->Sponsor->find('all',
        array('conditions' => array("NOT" => array("Sponsor.logo_id" => null))));
    $this->set('sponsors', $sponsors);
}
```

You now have access to `$sponors` in any view.

And it may be best to place the data in to an element and cache it for a suitable amount of time to avoid constantly having to query the database (depending on other factors such as page load/other intensive queries etc.

Comment: Oh, so not put this in the beforeFilter() but in the element? I thought that was against MVC rules?

Comment: the above code should go in your `beforeFilter` in your `app_controller` but if performance is an issue you can cache the query and pass the data in to an element, which can also be cached. If caching/performance isn't an issue; don't worry about it. I'd still use an element to display the output; so you can quickly reuse it in all your layouts.

Comment: FYI difference between `beforeFilter` and `beforeRender`: `beforeFilter` runs before the action is called, so it can tweak data and such. Settings vars in `beforeFilter` runs the possibility of being overwritten in an action, so I would suggest using `beforeRender` for this. Also, check out this plugin for caching the query results: https://github.com/jeremyharris/cacher

Answer (score 0):

- You could create an element in the element folder and then create a footer.ctp file there.
- Now, add `<?php echo $this->element('footer'); ?>` in your Layouts/default.ctp file

This way for every page the footer will be loaded. This is an elegant way and you can put other things also in Elements folder like header,pagination etc.